# Can I disable remote queue access in RabbitMQ cluster?

Tags: rabbitmq

When creating a RabbitMQ cluster, non-mirrored queues from other nodes are "remotely accessible" from other nodes.

To a naive developer they will seemingly be able to publish to and consume from any node in an cluster and it will give them a false sense of high-availability.

If the node hosting the queue dies, the consumer will no longer be able to reach the queue from the other node.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour so that it's obvious that one has to either have a mirrored queue or needs to create a distinct queues on each server, consume from both and then handle duplicates.

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible disable this behaviour, this is one of the main reasons why you create a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible disable this behaviour, this is one of the main reasons why you create a cluster.

BTW, you can create a federated cluster by using [federation plug-in](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html).

So you can:

1. have isolated nodes
2. share only the `exchanges` or/and `queues` you prefer.